# asp.net - public static functions using globally

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET C#. I try to follow this tutorial page to make a function using globally, but no luck.
https://web.archive.org/web/20210612122420/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122403-1.aspx

What I try to do is use a function global any where in my code. I have a function called "FormatDateNoTime".  I have create a Class file under App_Code folder. But when I call that function in one of my code behind page (example Page1.aspx.cs), it gives me the error:

Error: The name 'MyClass' does not exist in the current context

MyClass.cs file under the App_Code folder.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1
/// </summary>
public class MyClass
{

        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //

        public static string FormatDateNoTime(string input)            {
            string thedate;
            DateTime strDate = DateTime.Parse(input);
            thedate = strDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            return thedate;
        }
}
```

The code in my Page1.aspx.cs calling the FormateNoTime function

```
TextBox BeginDate = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("BeginDate");
BeginDate.Text = MyClass.FormatDateNoTime(objDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BeginDate"].ToString());
```

It seems like other pages don't recognize this class.function().

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see a couple of compile errors with the snippet you wrote above: One is, make sure that you defined input in the class MyClass as a static variable and Second is, while calling FormatDateNoTime method, you are passing just one argument. Have a look at them once

Comment: There's no way that code is ever compiled: wrong number of arguments when calling the function, and the function looks for an input variable that does not exist. This is cs101 stuff.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Can you please help me correct my codes above if possible?  Thanks for reply.

Comment: Why are you passing `object ` and `EventArgs` parameters?? They are meant for event handlers..

Comment: Sorry, I am new. I have updated the code to pass a string now. Stilll not able to recognize MyClass.FormatDateNoTime function from another page.

Comment: Update definition of the method in your question

Comment: still getting an error "The name 'MyClass' does not exist in the current context".  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Right click the source file in App_Code and set its **"Build Action"** property to **"Compile"**. Click on the .cs file in App_Code and hit **F4** key (or right click -> Properties), and you should see an option for **"Build Action"**
That way, it will build the code in your App_Code folder, and you should be able to access your static method in your class. If the above doesn't help, remove the class from the app_code and drop it in the root folder and try compiling it.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I right click the MyClass.cs file and hit F4, but don't see any "Build Action", I only see two FileName and Full Page. any suggestion?

Comment: Right click on the MyClass.cs file and go to properties. It should look like this: http://dimarzionist.files.wordpress.com/2008/07/build-action.jpg

Comment: Thanks @tranceporter, I think this is a right track, but some how I could not figure out to the cs file in App_Code from "Build Action" to "Compile"

Answer (score 1):

The code you have doesn't compile.  I'm pretty sure Visual Studio is throwing an error when you try to run it; pay attention to what it's saying.

Also, change the following:

```
public static string FormatDateNoTime(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string thedate;
    DateTime strDate = DateTime.Parse(input);
    thedate = strDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    return thedate;
}
```

To

```
public static string FormatDateNoTime(String input)
{
    string thedate;
    DateTime strDate = DateTime.Parse(input);
    thedate = strDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    return thedate;
}
```

I'd go further and validate that the input is parseable into a DateTime, but that's for you to explore.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I changed the code as you suggested, but still getting error the "Error: The name 'MyClass' does not exist in the current context".  So I need to Compile this class? How?  Sorry, I am new.